How to read information stored in /sys from kernel space
I'm porting a Linux device driver that needs to work the information that another device driver publishes to sysfs. The web is full of explanations on how to populate sysfs (readable from user space) but I have not yet found how a device driver can consult the information available in sysfs. Who gives me a suggestion? For example, I would like to read in kernel space the same information returned by this user space command:
cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:04\:0e.0/resource
Thank you all!!
